# VS Code pycodestyle not recognizing errors

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycodestyle

I'm using Atom as code editor on Ubuntu 20.04 and I currently try whether VS Code might be a replacement for my purposes.
One thing that annoys me a lot with VS code is that linting doesn't work as expected - and as I was used to with Atom. The below will be specifically for pycodestyle.

One issue is that quite a lot of warnings are not reported at all, such as e225 or e303.

Another is that too long lines are ignored at all once I increase the 80 character limit to 120 by adding the args "--line-length" and "120".

How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions you mentioned are the requirements of "flake8". You need to install falke8 and yapf first by the following code :

```
pip install flake8
pip install yapf
```

Then we configure linting in vscode and add the following contents to **setting.json**(`ctrl+shift+P` and choose "preferences:open settings(json)"):

```
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
"python.linting.flake8Args": [
    "--max-line-length=120"
],
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false
```

In this way, the format recognition of flake8 is started, and your second problem can also be effectively solved. I made a simple reproduction:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however your suggestion unfortunately doesn't solve the problems for me. I exchanged my settings.json linting-related content by yours and installed yapf, but I still have the same problems. Here are the installed versions in  case that has any implications:
flake8==3.7.9
flake8-polyfill==1.0.2
yapf==0.32.0
code: 1.68.1

Comment: My flake8==4.0.1. At the same time, I can also get the error prompt by using the simple example of e225. I don't know why you didn't. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg0YB.png

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading flake8 fixed the issue. Now e2225 and e303 geht caught.